# Cocoa - how to catch if HDD is reading/writing some data

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there any way how to determine if HDD is reading or writing data in OS X ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Instruments tool in Xcode uses DTrace to do this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace